# Como fijar el atributo "summary" de una Preference a partir de su valor persistente en Android

Tags: android, android-fragment

Estoy desarrollando las preferencias para una aplicación Android, para ello he creado el fichero "preferences.xml" donde fijo las preferencias y su summary a partir del valor por defecto.

```
<EditTextPreference
    android:key="pref_ciudad"
    android:title="Ciudad"
    android:summary="Cáceres"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:defaultValue="Caceres" />
```

En el fragment de preferencias, he declarado un listener que detecta que la preferencia se ha cambiado, actualizando el campo summary y haciéndola persistente.

```
@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key ) {

    if (key.equals(KEY_PREF_CIUDAD)){
        Preference ciudadPref = findPreference( key );
        ciudadPref.setSummary(sharedPreferences.getString(key, ""));
        ciudadPref.setPersistent( true );
    } 
}
```

El problema surge al volver al fragment de preferencias, que vuelve a ejecutar el método onCreate y me fija el summary con el valor por defecto, por lo cual, éste no se corresponde con el contenido de la preferencia en ese momento.

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu método onCreate () de la clase SettingsFragment, necesitas obtener una referencia a sus SharedPreferences y luego ejecutar el método onSharedPreferenceChanged (). Tu onCreate () debería verse así:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

// Carga las preferencias desde un XML resource
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

//si estas usando shared preferences por defecto
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());

onSharedPreferenceChanged(sharedPrefs, getString(R.string.llave1));
onSharedPreferenceChanged(sharedPrefs, getString(R.string.llave2));

}
```

Donde llave1 y llave 2 son tus claves de preferencia (example_text y example_text1 en su caso) guardadas en tu archivo de cadenas. Tuve un problema al hacer esto sin referencias de cadenas, por lo que recomiendo extraerlos. Espero que te sirva

Comment: Funciona perfecto, muchas gracias por tu ayuda!